# FullCalendar - How Do You Remove the Today Button On Initialization?

Tags: fullcalendar

On FullCalendar's default initialization, you get a calendar that looks like:

[image]

Is there anyway to get rid of the `today` button by passing in a key to `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({})`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use [`header`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/) and leave out the `today` to have the today button not displayed.

```
{
    left:   'title',
    center: '',
    right:  'prev,next'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is been changed to [`headerToolbar`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar) in v5+

```
headerToolbar: {
    start: 'title', // will normally be on the left. if RTL, will be on the right
    center: '',
    end: 'prev,next' // will normally be on the right. if RTL, will be on the left
}
```